# How do I graph a function with a local minimum without using calculus?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, graphing-functions

I am trying to graph a function with roots at $x=1$ with a multiplicity of $2$, $x=4$ with a multiplicity of $1$ that is $4$ degrees or higher. One end behavior is that as $x$ approaches infinity, $f(x)$ must approach negative infinity. The function must also be even.

Currently I have $f(x)=-(x-1)^2(x-4)$ but I am not sure how to modify this equation to include a local min at $x=3$. I am not allowed to use any form of calculus so derivatives are not allowed. What can I do to include a local min?

Comment: Also your function doesn't have $4$ degrees or higher...

Comment: This seems difficult to me without using calculus... Is it required that there is a local minimum at $x=3$ ?

Comment: Just made some edits. root must be at x=1 and 4, function must be even and should have a local min at x=3 according to the practice assignment. Equation currently accounts for things I have so far. Assignment is for algebra 2 so no calculus allowed.

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea. How would you even check that $x=3$ is a local minimum without using calculus?

Comment: It would be helpful if you state the question *exactly* as mentioned.  As of now in your first para, the condition of local minimum isn't there. Also your current function (presumably it is supposed to be a polynomial as you talk of its degrees?) isn't of degree $4$, it isn't even either.

Comment: As Macavity says, we really need the _exact_ wording of the exercise you're solving. For all we know now, one possibility is that it's not really asking you to _write down an expression_ for your function, just to sketch the graph of _some_ function that satisfies the conditions, freehand. That would be a lot less work. (And you can just blatantly claim your hand drawing _is_ a polynomial, thanks to the Weierstrass approximation theorem -- the number of roots will ensure it has the required high degree).

Answer (score 3):

Here are your listed conditions:

- root at $x=1$ with multiplicity $2$.
- root at $x=4$ with multiplicity $1$.
- degree at least $4$.
- $\lim_{x \to \infty}=-\infty$
- local minimum at $x=3$.
- Even function

A polynomial that would satisfies this is

$$-(x+4)(x+3)^2(x+1)^2(x-1)^2(x-3)^2(x-4)$$

Comment: I see, i missed that. thanks

Comment: Of course! I missed this.